# Running test site from live site URL?

Tags: apache, virtualhost, system-administration

Let's say I have a test site at test.site.com and the live site is www.site.com. They are both hosted on the same Linux Apache server and we are using VirtualHosts to indicate what the document root for each of the sites is.

The two sites are completely different in their backend but are meant to look identical (they run different CMS and have completely different file and URL structures). Before pushing the test site to live we'd obviously want to make sure all links and everything work perfectly when the url is www.site.com for the site without actually pushing it to live. Normally I would do this with two separate servers and simply changing my own hosts file to point the live domain to the test server IP but in this configuration they both share the same IP.

Is there a way to achieve this in my current set up? I was hoping I could make a conditional vhost directive that only takes effect for one IP (our office static IP) but it looks like that might not be possible?

For going live I was simply thinking of updating the vhosts file to change the document root for the virtual hosts and restart apache, but I don't know what to do for testing with the live url (www.site.com).

Answer (score 0):

If you ask me this shouldnt be an issue if your CMS is build in a way that it saves urls as relative urls. I would suggest that on page load you define what the domain should be, like

```
<?php
    define('DOMAIN', 'http://example.com');
?>
```

and then use that global variable to create links to you pages. This way it does not matter what domain you are on as long you do not have some code that implies that you are on a specific domain. Other than that I don`t see why there would be problems if you switch domains that the site runs on.